# how to convert json file into csv file using unix shellscript or command-line?

Tags: postgresql, shell, command-line

i have file example.json file. but i want to convert into csv file, so on csv file i can insert the data into external table using postgresSQL.

there is alternative way to convert it ? or there is way to convert it using unix shellscript or just direct use postgresSQL to insert the example.json file into external table ?

Comment: Why not use database functions and operators like `jsonb_to_record` or `->>`?

Comment: [Convert JSON array into CSV](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/570565)